# Turn off tkinter canvas line, but not delete the line

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Pretty much the subject line says it all.  I just want to be able to turn off the line, undisplay it.  I don't want to delete the line or the tag reference to the line.  I want to use a checkbutton and once the line is drawn, done through a database, I want to be able to turn on and off the line with the checkbutton, without having to replace the tag in the line list everytime I turn the line back on, err in that case I would have to redraw the line from scratch.  How do I turn I line off?  I haven't tried but I don't think the disable feature is for the this purpose.

Comment: Could you simply swap the colour of the line from invisible (`fill = ""`) to whatever it was before?

Comment: You win.  I didn't even think about that possibilty.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the canvas's `.itemconfig()` method to switch your line between `state=HIDDEN` and `state=NORMAL`.